# Display same SQL attribute from different joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to display data from 3 tables (whose scheme I did not create myself).
The tables have these simplified attributes:

```
table1: messageID, fromID
table2: messageID, toID
table3: id, displayName
```

id in table3 corresponds to fromID and toID.

I want to display a view of messageID, fromDisplayName, toDisplayName.

What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT table1.messageID as id, displayName as fromDisplayName, displayName as toDisplayName
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.messageID = table2.messageID
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.fromID = table3.id AND table2.toID = table3.id
```

Obviously, displayName will be the same one both time. How do I get the two different displayNames to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT t1.messageID, 
        fromName.displayName as fromDisplayName, 
        toName.displayName as toDisplayName
 FROM table1 t1
 JOIN table2 t2 
   ON t1.messageID = t2.messageID
 JOIN table3 fromName
   ON t1.fromID = fromName.id
 JOIN table3 toName
   ON t2.toID = toName.id
```